# Do other species have a different (native) word for humanoids?

Tags: star-trek

In Star Trek, most of the species we meet are humanoid. However, the origin of this word is clearly coming from humans of Earth. I am aware that the use the word "humanoid" by members of non-human species can be attributed to the universal translator, making it understandable for the viewer.

But, has ever a member of another species used a different (native to them) word for describing a humanoid?

For example, a Klingon referring to someone as Klingonoid?

Comment: Betazoid, perhaps?

Comment: https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Vulcanoid

Comment: Betazoid is the name of the member of the species, so I would assume that the -oid suffix is just coincidence. Vulcanoid is nice, although non-canon, which agrees with me not remembering any Vulcanoids in canon, except for a proto-Vulcan (humanoid).

Comment: According to http://klingonska.org/dict/ humanoid in klingon is "yoq" and human is "human," if I understand correctly.

Comment: https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Felinoid

Comment: https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Ursinoid

Comment: Felinoids are not humanoids, and I do not think that they ever refer to another species than themselves as felinoids. Perhaps my question needs rephrasing.

Comment: @Kai - would be nice, if used in canon :)

Comment: It depends on what's considered canon as the website claims to be compiling from a variety of sources -- those two words are sourced as coming from the Klingon Dictionary by Marc Okrand.

Comment: Azetbur (daughter of Gorkon) once called the Federation a 'homosapiens only club'

Comment: @EdmundDantes: "I do not think that they ever refer to another species than themselves as felinoids" - the link you were commenting on uses "felinoid" as a collective term for cat-like species, and it lists several of them. (In terms of the discussion topic, though, this brings us full-circle, of course - obviously, "felinoid" is a term originating on Earth, as an alien species would hardly describe themselves by referring to an alien (from their point of view) animal.)